# Multiple Accounts

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts, duplicate-accounts

I read in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) that accounts can be merged.

I would like to know the following:

1. Is account merging 100% fair game or is it frowned upon?
2. Can you merge accounts more than once? How often?
3. Is it a fairly automated process or a lot of work behind the scenes?
4. What exactly goes into ***confirm your ownership*** mentioned in the linked article above?

**EDIT:**

I want to add the following clarification based on the comments section:

I have always been a good **SO** citizen.

I have never had a banned account.

I have no intention of bypassing any rules: I just assume it would be easily detected by the system.

Comment: We frown upon multiple accounts that are used to bypass system limitations. Such as question bans or the ability to vote for your own content. If you accidentally created duplicate accounts then there are no limitations on merging.

Comment: I think there's some hidden question here. Why do you need to know all that and what do you intend to do with that information? That will help us let you know if it's "ok" or not. Because account merging is the exception, so if you want to use it that often (as implied by your question), there is a goal you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/merge-accounts/info as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I added clarifications in the question body itself.

Comment: @Patrice, I added clarifications in the question body itself.

Comment: @sdk Well... that doesn't really help highlight why you want to know all that, even with those clarifications. What are you trying to accomplish with the information you will gain by having your 4 questions answered? If it's "I made a bunch of mistakes and have 3-4 accounts lying around, I'll merge them, is it ok?" then yes, it's ok, as Martijn said. If it's for something else... being straightforward about what you'll do should help others tell you how it'll be seen.

Comment: For the past several years, I have been operating a second account under the name "Jon Skeet". I would like to merge that one with my current one... ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic no, I AM SPARTAC... I mean I AM JON SKEET

Comment: @sdk, you keep making edits but you are still avoiding saying why do you need this? This one looks like an XY problem, but the X is still missing.

Comment: It seems a bit odd wanting to know *how often* you can merge accounts.